# Looping through Dataframe columns to treat outliers not removing the outliers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, outliers

I am trying to treat outliers in the OnlineRetail dataset from kaggle. There are two float64 columns that I want to treat for outliers and so applied a for loop to do the same. Here is the code:

```
# making a list of numeric columns for outlier analysis
numcols=[x for x in df.columns if df[x].dtype=='float64']

for i,col in enumerate(numcols):
  # cleaning outliers
  # calculating quantiles
  q1=df[col].quantile(0.25)
  q3=df[col].quantile(0.75)

  # defining IQR(inter-quartile range)
  iqr=q3-q1

  # defining upper and lower limits
  upper=q3 + (1.5 * iqr)
  lower=q1 - (1.5 * iqr)

  # redefining data
  df=df[(df[col]<=upper) & (df[col]>=lower)]
  plt.subplot(1,2,i+1)
  sns.boxplot(df[col])
```

Some changes are made in the table as indicated by the describe method but the outliers are still present.
**Statistics before applying outlier treatment:
**

```
        Quantity        UnitPrice   
count   392353.000000   392353.000000   
mean    13.148496       2.998207    
std     181.636906      15.045821   
min     1.000000        0.000000    
25%     2.000000        1.250000    
50%     6.000000        1.950000    
75%     12.000000       3.750000    
max     80995.000000    8142.750000
```

**Statistics after applying outlier treatment:
**

```
        Quantity        UnitPrice   
count   358418.000000   358418.000000   
mean    14.099339       2.136547    
std     189.995838      1.535920    
min     1.000000        0.000000    
25%     2.000000        0.850000    
50%     6.000000        1.650000    
75%     12.000000       2.950000    
max     80995.000000    7.500000
```

However when I apply the same outlier treatment on the columns individually the data looks better (there is still some skewness present but that is acceptable)

```
      Quantity          UnitPrice   
count 333085.000000     333085.000000   
mean  7.552388          2.194495    
std   6.777632          1.546085    
min   1.000000          0.000000    
25%   2.000000          1.250000    
50%   6.000000          1.650000    
75%   12.000000         2.950000    
max   27.000000         7.500000
```

Can someone please help me make sense of this? I will be grateful.

Comment: what does ` df=df[(df[col]<=upper) & (df[col]>=lower)]` do? You are just subsetting a lot of values that lie within the lower and upper bound. meaning you are throwing away/removing outliers. Yet you stated that you do not want to remove outliers. your redefinition is therefore incorrect. consider using a mask. ie `df[df<lower] = lower` to cap it at the lower end etc.

Comment: After removing the outliers, you get a new population, new descriptive statistics, and… potentially new outliers. You shouldn't remove outliers just by principle but rather for a specific reason, think of what is yours.